# Group from 2 tables and make them unique array in php

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have orders table and shipments table which also have relationship to their items :

Orders :

```
//orders table
+----+----------------+----------------+
| id | destination_id | requested_date |
+----+----------------+----------------+
|  1 |              1 | 2022-08-31     |
|  2 |              1 | 2022-09-01     |
+----+----------------+----------------+

//order_items table
+----------+-------------+------+
| order_id | material_id | qty  |
+----------+-------------+------+
|        1 |          39 | 1000 |
|        1 |           7 | 1500 |
|        1 |           4 |  250 |
|        2 |          48 | 5000 |
|        2 |          33 | 1500 |
+----------+-------------+------+
```

Shipments:

```
//shipments table
+----+----------------+---------------+
| id | destination_id | shipment_date |
+----+----------------+---------------+
|  1 |              1 | 2022-08-27    |
+----+----------------+---------------+

//shipment_items table
+-------------+-------------+------+
| shipment_id | material_id | qty  |
+-------------+-------------+------+
|           1 |          39 |  900 |
|           1 |           4 |  450 |
|           1 |          12 | 2000 |
+-------------+-------------+------+
```

Materials table:

```
+----+------------------------------+
| id | name                         |
+----+------------------------------+
|  4 | Cengkeh                      |
|  7 | TJM Besuki Kasaran B 2021    |
| 12 | TJM Bondowoso Kasaran B 2021 |
| 33 | TJM Madura Lama A 2019       |
| 39 | TJM Paiton Kasaran 2019      |
| 48 | TJM Paiton Kasaran C 2020    |
+----+------------------------------+
```

Destinations table :

```
+----+-------------------+
| id | name              |
+----+-------------------+
|  1 | Malang-Pagelaran  |
|  2 | Tulungagung-Pakel |
|  3 | Malang-Araya      |
+----+-------------------+
```

I'd like to get the balance of orders for each site and items/materials by date and group them, something like this :

```
[
    'destination' => 'Destination name',
    'material' => 'Name of item/material',
    'order' => 'qty of order',
    'shipment' => 'qty of shipment',
    'balance' => 'shipment - order'
]
```

what i've tried so far using laravel :

```
$from = Carbon::now()->subDays(30)->format('Y-m-d');
        $to = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');

        $orders = \App\Models\MaterialOrder::select('materials.name as material','branches.name as destination','units.conversion','order.qty','requested_date')
            ->leftJoin('branches','destination_id','=','branches.id')
            ->leftJoin('material_order_items as order','material_orders.id','=','order.material_order_id')
            ->leftJoin('materials','materials.id','=','order.material_id')
            ->leftJoin('units','order.uom','=','units.name')
            ->where('material_orders.status',1)
            ->whereBetween('material_orders.created_at',[$from,$to])
            ->get()->toArray();

        $shipments = \App\Models\MaterialShipment::select('materials.name as material','branches.name as destination','units.conversion','shipment.qty','shipment_date')
            ->leftJoin('branches','destination_id','=','branches.id')
            ->leftJoin('material_shipment_items as shipment','material_shipments.id','=','shipment.material_shipment_id')
            ->leftJoin('materials','materials.id','=','shipment.material_id')
            ->leftJoin('units','shipment.uom','=','units.name')
            ->where('material_shipments.status',1)
            ->whereBetween('material_shipments.created_at',[$from,$to])
            ->get()->toArray();

        $collectedData = collect(array_unique(array_merge($orders,$shipments), SORT_REGULAR))->groupBy(['destination','material']);
```

but got this result instead :

```
[
    "TJM Paiton Kasaran 2019" => [
        0 => [
          "material" => "TJM Paiton Kasaran 2019"
          "destination" => "Malang-Pagelaran"
          "conversion" => 1
          "qty" => 1000
          "requested_date" => "2022-08-31"
        ],
        1 => [
          "material" => "TJM Paiton Kasaran 2019"
          "destination" => "Malang-Pagelaran"
          "conversion" => 1
          "qty" => 900
          "shipment_date" => "2022-08-27"
        ]
    ],
    "TJM Besuki Kasaran B 2021" => [
        0 => [
          "material" => "TJM Besuki Kasaran B 2021"
          "destination" => "Malang-Pagelaran"
          "conversion" => 1
          "qty" => 1500
          "requested_date" => "2022-08-31"
        ]
    ],
    "Cengkeh" => [
        0 => array:5 [
          "material" => "Cengkeh"
          "destination" => "Malang-Pagelaran"
          "conversion" => 1
          "qty" => 250
          "requested_date" => "2022-08-31"
        ],
        1 => [
          "material" => "Cengkeh"
          "destination" => "Malang-Pagelaran"
          "conversion" => 1
          "qty" => 450
          "shipment_date" => "2022-08-27"
        ]
    ],
    "TJM Paiton Kasaran C 2020" => [
        0 => [
          "material" => "TJM Paiton Kasaran C 2020"
          "destination" => "Malang-Pagelaran"
          "conversion" => 1
          "qty" => 5000
          "requested_date" => "2022-09-01"
        ]
    ],
    "TJM Madura Lama A 2019" => [
        0 => array:5 [
          "material" => "TJM Madura Lama A 2019"
          "destination" => "Malang-Pagelaran"
          "conversion" => 1
          "qty" => 1500
          "requested_date" => "2022-09-01"
        ]
    ],
    "TJM Bondowoso Kasaran B 2021" => [
        0 => [
          "material" => "TJM Bondowoso Kasaran B 2021"
          "destination" => "Malang-Pagelaran"
          "conversion" => 1
          "qty" => 2000
          "shipment_date" => "2022-08-27"
        ]
    ]
]
```

How to achieve this ?

Update :
single results for orders and shipments

```
//Orders

array:5 [
  0 => array:5 [
    "material" => "TJM Paiton Kasaran 2019"
    "destination" => "Malang-Pagelaran"
    "conversion" => 1
    "qty" => 1000
    "requested_date" => "2022-08-31"
  ]
  1 => array:5 [
    "material" => "TJM Besuki Kasaran B 2021"
    "destination" => "Malang-Pagelaran"
    "conversion" => 1
    "qty" => 1500
    "requested_date" => "2022-08-31"
  ]
]

//Shipments
array:3 [
  0 => array:5 [
    "material" => "TJM Paiton Kasaran 2019"
    "destination" => "Malang-Pagelaran"
    "conversion" => 1
    "qty" => 900
    "shipment_date" => "2022-08-27"
  ]
  1 => array:5 [
    "material" => "Cengkeh"
    "destination" => "Malang-Pagelaran"
    "conversion" => 1
    "qty" => 450
    "shipment_date" => "2022-08-27"
  ]
  2 => array:5 [
    "material" => "TJM Bondowoso Kasaran B 2021"
    "destination" => "Malang-Pagelaran"
    "conversion" => 1
    "qty" => 2000
    "shipment_date" => "2022-08-27"
  ]
]
```

Comment: I'm less familiar with `leftJoin` but if you provide the output data of `$orders` and `$shipments` separately, then I can try it to achieve your goal. @owf

Comment: @JSTECH please check on the updated question, i added the outputs for $orders and $shipments

Comment: As far as I understand in balance, `qty of shipment * conversion of shipment - qty of order * conversion of order`. Is it correct or something else?

Comment: can you add one more field(let say, `unique_id`) to your `Orders` and `Shipments` data.  The `unique_id` must be common to both the tables data  (Orders & Shipments) but unique on own table data. So that it will be easy to extract the data otherwise it is not possible I think.

Comment: @JSTECH yes, it is correct , so the orders and shipments must connected by a unique id ?
i understand, that would be easey, but there is no way to connect them, as the orders and shipments is compeletely separated / connected each other in real life and no open/close order by shipment either, so we designed it without any relation betyween them